# Is it OK to call functions for default member initialization?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, default, member

Is the following code good and valid? Can you provide a quote from the standard?

```
class C
{
public:
    int i0 = 10;
    int i1 = i0 * 10;
    int i2 = get_int();
    int get_int()
    {
        return i1 * 100;
    }
};
```

Comment: I would trust the compiler (be sure to enable warnings) on this one, does it let you do this? Just by common sense - when would this execute? Before the constructor? Then you should not be calling a non-static method. After? Seems wrong too.

Comment: @dratenik It would be executed inside of the constructor, as if OP did `C() : ... i2(get_int()) {}`. It's fine as long as the member functions don't use not-yet-initialized class members.

Comment: Compiler eats this with no complaint, it's likely valid. Should you actually do this? Wouldn't more complex cases suffer from an initialization order problem? Looks like a footgun.

Comment: It can be used very conveniently in some cases. If a ctor doesn't have parameters, you can define members in place and don't bother about duplication (code bloat).

Comment: This is valid, but dangerous as changing the order of members will break the code.

Comment: @Ayxan Haqverdili If you do this in the list, changing the order of member declarations also breaks the code. Actually you must think what you are doing.

Comment: @dratenik And what order problems? There are actually fewer problems, because you don't need syncronize list order with members declaration order.

Comment: @olekstolar and everyone who maintains the code afterwards and touches the method in question must think (and be aware of the constraint). [Thinking hurts](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0048076). I would aim to decrease the cognitive load for maintaining my software, not add to it.

Comment: @olekstolar it's dangerous not because you're not using a member initializer list, but because you depend on the order of member initialization. That's what I meant in the previous comment anyway.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili initialization of members in the list also depends on the order of member declaration. E.g. if there is some member A that another member B is dependent on, then A must be declared first (and the order in  member initializer list doesn't matter).

Comment: @olekstolar I never claimed otherwise. My point is *In general* you don't use members to initialize each other. When you do (whether in initialization list or elsewhere), that's dangerous.